# MySQL Table Editing w/ PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm unsure how to get my editfields.php file to load when an administrator selects the Edit button for whatever row in my SQL table (adminlogin.php).

I feel my editfields.php file has the right stuff, but I'm stuck when it comes to getting the data and having that data display in my view as opposed to what I have printing according to my edituser function.

** PLEASE ignore the approve function for now, as well as the if conditionak in adminlogin.php, both items for separate discussion **

Below are the following files:

Controller (Myform.php)

```
<?php

class Myform extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); 
  }

  public function index(){
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[first_name]', 'First Name', 'required'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[last_name]', 'Last Name', 'required'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[email]', 'Email Address', 'required|trim'); 

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('myform');
          }
              else{
                $user = $this->input->post('user');
                $company = $this->input->post('company'); 
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($user);
                print_r($company); 
                $this->db->insert("User_Inputs", $user);        
                $this->db->insert("companies", $company);       
                redirect("/myform/successmessage");
              }
  }

    public function successmessage(){
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }          

  public function getDatabase(){
    $data['users'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->result();
    $this->load->view('adminlogin', $data);

  }

public function approve(){
    $id = $this->input->get("user_id"); 
    $this->db->where("id", $id); 
  $data['user'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->row();
    echo "<pre>"; 
  print_r($this->db->last_query()); 
    print_r($data);
    echo "<h1>". $data['user']->email."</h1>";  

    die();
}

public function edituser(){
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->row();
  echo "<pre>"; 
  print_r($this->db->last_query()); 
  print_r($data);
  echo "<h3>Showing results for ID #". $data['user']->id."</h3>";  

  die();

  /* $data = array($id);
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $this->db->update('users', $data); */

}

}
```

Table View (adminlogin.php)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>


<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <center>
    <thead> 
        <tr style="font-size: 24; color: white;">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </center>
    <tbody style="background-color: #F0F8FF;">  
        <?php foreach($users as $u){
        $class = "btn btn-primary";
        $button = "Approve";  
             if ($u->id == 7){
                $class = "btn btn-danger"; 
                $button = "Deny";
        } ?>
        <tr style="font-size: 20;">
            <td><?php echo $u->first_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u->last_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u->email; ?></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="/ci/index.php/myform/edituser?user_id=<?php echo $u->id;?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="<?php echo $class;?>" href="/ci/index.php/myform/approve?user_id=<?php echo $u->id;?>"><?php echo $button;?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Edit View (editfields.php)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit User Info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

<div>

<p><strong>ID:</strong><?php echo $id; ?></p>

<strong>First Name</strong><input type="text" name='first_name' value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>"?>"/><br/>

<strong>Last Name</strong><input type="text" name='last_name' value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Email</strong><input type="hidden" name='email' value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The most basic, fundamental example I want to achieve at this juncture is at the following, though this example may not fit according to my code:

http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/

Comment: if you want people to ignore  parts of your code, then don't post those parts. Just make sure you have a complete example.

Comment: @Aaron thanks, will do in the future.

Comment: @Aaron, do you have any feedback?

Comment: your public function edituser() does not loading any view

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my answer with the full test code for controller and views:

**Myform.php**

```
  <?php


class Myform extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Added form and url helper so all functions can use them.
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[first_name]', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[last_name]', 'Last Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[email]', 'Email Address', 'required|trim|valid_email');

        // The only reason i store the values in this variable is to
        // allow the re-use of the same form for both index and edituser
        // functions. This allows the re-population rule to work.
        $form['dbValue'] = [
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('user[first_name]'),
            'last_name'  => $this->input->post('user[last_name]'),
            'email'      => $this->input->post('user[email]'),
            'id'         => $this->input->post('id'),
        ];

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform', $form);
        }
        else
        {
            // I've disabled company here as i could not find any reference to it
            // in the form you have given as an example
            $user = $this->input->post('user');
            // $company = $this->input->post('company');
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($user);
            // print_r($company);


            if ($this->input->post('id') !== '' && $this->input->post('id') !==NULL)
            {
                // id is defined so we update the user
                $this->db
                    ->where('id', (int) $this->input->post('id'))
                    ->update("User_Inputs", $user);
            }
            else
            {
                // id is not define so we create the user
                $this->db->insert("User_Inputs", $user);
            }


            // $this->db->insert("companies", $company);
            redirect("/myform/getDatabase");
        }
    }

    public function successmessage()
    {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }

    public function getDatabase()
    {
        $data['users'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->result();
        $this->load->view('adminlogin', $data);
    }

    public function approve()
    {
        $id           = $this->input->get("user_id");
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->row();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->db->last_query());
        print_r($data);
        echo "<h1>" . $data['user']->email . "</h1>";

        die();
    }

    public function edituser($user_id = NULL)
    {
        // Just making sure we are capturing the id as an integer
        $user_id = (int) $user_id;

        // Get the user based on the $user_id
        $data['user'] = $this->db
            ->where('id', $user_id)
            ->get("User_Inputs")
            ->row();

        // We will use the below variable to set the form fields to the correct values.
        $form['dbValue'] = [
            'first_name' => $data['user']->first_name,
            'last_name'  => $data['user']->last_name,
            'email'      => $data['user']->email,
            'id'         => $user_id
        ];

        $this->load->view('myform', $form);
    }

}
```

**View: *adminlogin.php***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>


        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <center>
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="font-size: 24; color: white;">
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </center>
                <tbody style="background-color: #F0F8FF;">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($users as $u)
                    {
                        $class  = "btn btn-primary";
                        $button = "Approve";
                        if ($u->id == 7)
                        {
                            $class  = "btn btn-danger";
                            $button = "Deny";
                        }
                        ?>
                        <tr style="font-size: 20;">
                            <td><?php echo $u->first_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $u->last_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $u->email; ?></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo site_url('myform/edituser/' . $u->id); ?>">Edit</a></td>
                            <td><a class="<?php echo $class; ?>" href="<?php echo site_url('myform/approve/' . $u->id); ?>"><?php echo $button; ?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

**View: *myform.php***

```
  <?php
// if the set_value default values are not set set them to NULL


echo form_open('myform');

echo form_label('First Name', 'first_name');
echo form_input('user[first_name]', set_value('user[first_name]', isset($dbValue['first_name'])) ? $dbValue['first_name'] : '' );

echo form_label('Last Name', 'last_name');
echo form_input('user[last_name]', set_value('user[last_name]', isset($dbValue['last_name'])) ? $dbValue['last_name'] : '' );

echo form_label('Email', 'email');
echo form_input('user[email]', set_value('user[email]', isset($dbValue['email'])) ? $dbValue['email'] : '' );

echo form_hidden('id', set_value('id', isset($dbValue['id'])) ? $dbValue['id'] : '' );

echo form_submit('Submit', 'submit');

echo form_close();
echo validation_errors();
```

Comment: that is helpful. question: why when i successfully load /myform/edituser/user_id/XX does it not load the editfields.php view? i know it has something to do with the function itself, but anytime for instance that i call the load helper on the editfields.php view, it shows the correct route but it's not showing the form I'm hoping would load via editfields.php.

Comment: wouldn't it help to use the active record class? update()?

Comment: The reason it does not load the editfields.php is because you do not tell the function to load it.

You can add it the below code just before die(); in the edituser function in your controller.

 `$this->load->view('editfields');`

This requires off course to have the editfields.php in your view folder.

Comment: so i did the following which worked: `public function edituser(){
 $data['user'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->row();
  $this->load->view('editfields', $data['user']);
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $this->db->update('User_Inputs', $data['user']);
  
}` but while it loads my editfields view, simultaneously its showing assignment error that `id` is unassigned variable. what's the issue here?

Comment: in your original function you had the the id defined as $data['user']->id

Comment: ok. can you explain/show how that would need to be incorporated into my revised function?

Comment: i've  updated the response, however i have a question, why do you get the user data from the database then update it back unmodified immediately? Also using row() function you just fetch a single row from the user_inputs table.

Comment: that worked, makes sense. only remaining obstacle is that regardless of which row i click to edit, it brings me ID 1. does this tether back to your last question regarding fetching a single row? what's the solve?

Comment: well, it looks like this function is used to update the existing user information. so in your view where you have all users listed, for each edit button add the following:  <a href="<?php echo site_url('myform/edituser/'.$id);?>">Edit</a> obviously in your view you must have the $id available for each user.

Comment: hm...it's still loading ID 1

Comment: i'm stumped, my URL continues to read /myform/edituser/user_id/XX though, per your direction, I changed the path so it would pull $id for each user, as in /myform/edituser/$id

Comment: see updated function that takes $id as a parameter and if the parameter is set then uses that to filter for the userid using the "id" column from the User_Inputs table

Comment: ok, here's my code though I'm thrown an error, line 59 of controller, trying to get property of non-object `public function edituser($id=NULL){
  if($id!=NULL){
      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      }
 $data['user'] = $this->db->get("User_Inputs")->row();
  $this->db->where('id', $data['user']->id);
  $this->db->update('User_Inputs', $data['user']);
  $this->load->view('editfields', $data['user']);
}`

Comment: Does the id exist in your table?

Comment: no, thats a good point. honeslty, i thought it was assigned automatically regardless of it being displayed or not.

Comment: any further guidance?

Comment: how would i add id?

Comment: i've updated my response with full working examples of the controller and forms (only for index() and edituser() forms.

Comment: ok awesome - my problem is that the last line of the controller calls the wrong form. it's supposed to load my editfields view, which then would need to give the option of updating first name, last name, email (not id). my problem beffore wasn't that the editfields view isn't working. it worked however selecting edit from any row would return the same id (id 1). from there my goal is to THEN navigate back to the adminlogin view relfecting whatever manual changes have been made.

Comment: well, feel free to mondify.
my solution would give you the admin form (getDatabase) and when you click on edit, it would give you the edit form pre-populated with the values, if you click on submit, it will update that line only, and return to the admin page automatically, set up a new codeigniter instance and test it out with my code.

Comment: i do have one additional question...i'm 100% new to AJAX, but i think it'd be fun to implement it so that say, when admin clicks "Approve" on a row, the view seamlessly loads a stylized tag of sorts showing that that row has been approved. how would you go about in doing this?

Comment: i've added a second answer

Comment: if i wanted to incorporate a bootstrap modal over table for editing user row, would the actual modal content go into my adminlogin file or editfields file? I can't find documentation clearly laying this out.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for ajax see the below modifications:

I've added jquery library and bootstrap library,

**adminlogin.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>


        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <center>
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="font-size: 24; color: white;">
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </center>
                <tbody style="background-color: #F0F8FF;">
                    <?php foreach ($users as $u): ?>
                        <?php
                        // added approve class
                        $class  = "approve btn btn-primary";
                        $button = "Approve";
                        if ($u->id == 7)
                        {
                            $class  = " deny btn btn-danger";
                            $button = "Deny";
                        }

                        ?>
                        <!-- id is added to each row to uniquely identify them so we can change it's color-->
                        <tr id="row_<?= $u->id ?>"style="font-size: 20;">
                            <td><?php echo $u->first_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $u->last_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $u->email; ?></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-success"  href="<?php echo site_url('myform/edituser/' . $u->id); ?>">Edit</a></td>
                            <!-- data-id was added to store the user id -->
                            <td><a class="<?php echo $class; ?>" data-id="<?= $u->id ?>" href="<?php echo site_url('myform/approve/' . $u->id); ?>"><?php echo $button; ?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('.approve').on("click", function (e) {
                // prevent the browser to loading the page directly
                e.preventDefault();

                // get the user id from the button we clicked.
                var userid = $(this).data('id');

                //initiate ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        // on success add the bootstrap success class to the row
                        $('#row_' + userid).addClass('success')
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        // on error add boorstrap dange class to the row
                        $('#row_' + userid).addClass('danger')
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>



    </body>
</html>
```

for testing purposes i've changed the **myform/approve** function

```
public function approve()
    {

        //do something this is for testing
        $result = true;

        if ($result)
        {
            // success you have done was OK and we send back success code
            $this->output->set_status_header(200);
        } else
        {
            // failure we send back an 4* cient error code
            $this->output->set_status_header(400);
        }
    }
```